# WCF service available through different addresses

Tags: c#, wcf, web-config

Due to the nature of the tools that I need to use, I need to have access to a wcf service using both http and htpps.

Specifically, the service needs to be accessable through the following (base) urls:

Is it possible to do this in one service config and multiple endpoints?

The above cofiguration doesn't work for my service when I try to access it through localhost. Of course, the code tag around localhost is so I can submit my question.

Depending on what I adjust in the config I get a different error. But most of the time it's when I try to add an extra http endpoint next to an already existing https endpoint.

e.g.:
*Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the endpoint with binding WebHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [https].*

Or

*The HttpGetEnabled property of ServiceMetadataBehavior is set to true and the HttpGetUrl property is a relative address, but there is no http base address.  Either supply an http base address or set HttpGetUrl to an absolute address.*

What am I overlooking here?

Comment: "Doesn't work" is a very vague term.  What happens when you try the above?  Nothing?  Do you get any errors?

Comment: I've adjusted my question a bit but after checking with colleagues I think we've found a solution. Still need to test it a bit more in dev.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation it seems that it's not possible to have two endpoints with different SSL settings.

So if one endpoint of a service has SSL enabled, the other one needs it as well.

Unless someone else can proof that this is not correct, I have solved the issue by duplicating the service and thus creating two services. One has SSL enabled, the other one has it disabled.